# Default Android Full Screen Activity never sleeps

Tags: android, android-activity

When I create a completely new project with the full screen option, the activity never dims or goes to sleep. Why is this happening? I'm looking through the given code and none of it seems to affect the sleep parameters. My phone is dimming and going to sleep on other apps so I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In res/layout/activity_fullscreen.xml

android:keepScreenOn="true"

This is keeping your screen on.